# How can I fixed the filter and Kernel Size of a CNN?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I have created `4 x 4` 2d images from a signal. Now, I want to feed this data to a Convolutional neural Network. How I can choose the nubmber of `filter, Kernel Size` for this small, shape and size of dataset (`4 x 4, 320 images`). Should I use maxpooling layer ?

**Note:**
I have already implemented a model for this dataset and **accuracy** is `78.125%`.  The model is,

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to input the values? or Which values to feed? also do add tensorflow in your tags for better exposure to the question.

Comment: @SoumyaKundu thanks.  No, I am looking for suggestion how I can choose Kernel size & depth of model for this data.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/deciding-optimal-filter-size-for-cnns-d6f7b56f9363 - refer here!

Comment: Why you need CNN for 4x4 i.e. 16 dimensions data? Do you believe that CNN will find something special but a simple model will not even if data is very small?

Comment: @10xAI Thanks for your response. I want to compare the best performance between ML and CNN. So, I did this. Is there any good way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the images are just 4x4 in size, you can do the following :

- You can resize the image to a much larger dimension like 28x28 and then use sharpen or histogram equalization to bring out the contrast. Then use a 3x3x16, 3x3x 32 kernel arrays in 2 convolutional layers. The rest is fully connected.
- The images can be input as 4x4 images but use a shorter neural net. One convolutional layer with padding and 3x3x 32 shape would do.
- Use something similar to [google nets, inception module](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-the-versions-of-the-inception-network-7fc52b863202), in which output from multiple convolutions are combined.